# In Linux, what would be the best way to recursively ZIP multiple directories at once?

Tags: linux, bash, zip

I have a directory, `/dir`, and it is full of other directories with no common naming scheme. So `/dir/EqcWTG` `/dir/SomeDirectoryName` `/dir/3435346` and so forth.

I would like to turn each one of these directories into a zip file. So basically I want to run `$ zip -r directoryname.zip directoryname` on every directory in `$(pwd)`.

What would be the easiest way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`find`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) this should work:

```
find /dir -not -name "dir" -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec zip -r '{}.zip' '{}' \;
```

Note how I have `/dir` as the main `find` path but also have `-not -name "dir"` so that parent directory is not archived. Next we limit the depth of the `find` scan with `-maxdepth 1` which means `find` will only search for immediate children of the path `/dir`. After that, we make sure to only act on directories with `-type d`. And finally we use `-exec` to run the magical `zip` command that will recursively compress all of the directories it finds; `{}` just equates to the directory name itself.

Another tact would be to use `-mindepth 1` instead of `-not -name "dir"` just in case a nested directory in the parent `/dir` structure somehow also goes by the name of `/dir` or has “dir” as a part of it’s name:

```
find /dir -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -execdir echo {} \;
```

Now those would create ZIP archives that will expand to the full `/dir` path; `/dir/EqcWTG`, `/dir/SomeDirectoryName`, `/dir/3435346`, etc… If you wanted standalone/relative ZIP archives you could use `-execdir` instead of `-exec` like this:

```
find /dir -not -name "dir" -maxdepth 1 -type d -execdir zip -r '{}.zip' '{}' \;
```

Same `-execdir` idea, but with `-mindepth 1` instead of `-not -name "dir"`:

```
find /dir -mindepth 1  -maxdepth 1 -type d -execdir zip -r '{}.zip' '{}' \;
```

Since `-execdir` forces the `find` command to act in the actual directory it has found something in—rather than the full path—that command would create similarly named ZIP archives which would expand to relative directories named `EqcWTG`, `SomeDirectoryName`, `3435346`, etc… But again, final usage/options you choose all depends on your final ZIP archiving needs.

Comment: It might be better to exclude `/dir` by using `-mindepth 1`, in case one of the subdirectories has the same name as the parent.

Comment: I appreciate the help. I actually went with the command provided yesterday and slightly modified it to be a bit simpler. `$ find * -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec zip -r {}.zip {} \;` accomplishes exactly what I wanted, I've used it on test directories as well as my live one for which I originally posted this question.